# TypedParameter is not used if the type is already register

Tags: c#, autofac

I have an unexpected behavior of the `TypedParameter` in Autofac. It ignored if the type is already register and I don't know if is it correct or how to obtain the expected behavior. Example:

I have a `Foo` class with the following constructor.

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(IEnumerable<IRule> rules)
    {..}
}
```

I've already register a lot of rules inside the builder (scanning the assembly), but when I resolve, I would like to pass an Autofac `TypedParameter` with a custom list of `IRules`

```
TypedParameter iocParam = new TypedParameter(typeof(IEnumerable<IRule>), rules);
var result = container.Resolve(FOO, iocParam);
```

The problem here is Autofac is ignoring myCustomListOfRules and creating a list with all available `IRules` already register in first place, instead of using the `TypedParameter`.

If I use a `NamedParameter`:

```
 NamedParameter iocParam = new NamedParameter("rules", myCustomListOfRules);
```

works fine, but I have to *hardcode* the name of the parameter instead of resolve it by the type.

Is it correct the behavior of the `TypedParameter` or there is a way to use it as I want?

Update:

I was doing something else bad because the `TypedParameter` has the expected behavior. The following example works as expected.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Autofac;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<Rule1>().As<IRule>();
            builder.RegisterType<Rule2>().As<IRule>();
            builder.RegisterType<Foo>();

            var resolver=builder.Build();

            // autofac resolve foo with all of available rules, ok¡
            var foo1=resolver.Resolve<Foo>();
            Console.WriteLine(foo1.GetNumberOfRules());

            // resolve with custom rules, ok¡
            var rules=new List<IRule>();
            rules.Add(new Rule1());
            TypedParameter param = new TypedParameter(typeof(IEnumerable<IRule>), rules);
            var foo2 = resolver.Resolve<Foo>(param);
            Console.WriteLine(foo2.GetNumberOfRules());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        IEnumerable<IRule> rules;
        public Foo(IEnumerable<IRule> rules)
        {
            this.rules = rules;
        }

        public int GetNumberOfRules()
        {
            return this.rules.Count();
        }
    }

    public interface IRule
    {
    }

    public class Rule1 : IRule
    {
    }

    public class Rule2 : IRule
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I was not able to repro this with Autofac v3.0.2 or with 2.6.3.862. Using the `TypedParameter` works as expected. Can you please create a small repro with compileable/working code?

Comment: nemewsv, you are right. I've updated with an example showing the correct behavior of the TypedParameter, sorry :/